# How to call proxy function in truffle

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle

I deployed openzepplin proxy contract on Arbitrum(Goerli) and when I call the contract function of the proxy contract(**read as proxy**), it shows an error **TypeError: contract.methods.getReservesList is not a function**

Proxy Contract: 0x205c72061e868Cc0D02b20Aa3cF9b73De9b11fAf

Implementation Contract: 0x3d3f5A05de5909502562F3607cB55C95240557c7

This is the truffle code:

````
const WalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const http = require("http");

let provider = new WalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
        phrase: '***'
    },
    providerOrUrl: "https://goerli-rollup.arbitrum.io/rpc"
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const dexABI = "contract-abi";

const contract_address = "0x205c72061e868Cc0D02b20Aa3cF9b73De9b11fAf";
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(dexABI, contract_address);
console.log(contract);

http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.url != '/favicon.ico') {
        try {
            const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            let user = accounts[0];
            let amount = "1000000000000000000";
            let asset = "0x0A5DA9BDFCc014632474B95D4EAdF0F250d5325A";
            let ref = 0;
           // console.log(user, amount, asset, ref);
            const record = await contract.methods.getReservesList().call();
            console.log(record);           

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        res.end();
    }
})
    .listen(8080);```
````